# Vs code doesn't regognize tkinter on pop os

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I have a code, where i use tkinter to make a window and stuff. It's a brawler picker for brawl stars. Im using pop os-linux and vs code and i have tried so many ways, but anything doesn't work.

When i run the code, i get this:

```
(.venv) sh-5.1$ python -u "/home/"my_name"/Documents/Vs-code_projektit/Joku.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/"my_name"/Documents/Vs-code_projektit/Joku.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

And in the vs code itself, it regognizes the tkinter and turns the text green, but after that nothing relating to tkinter doesn't work and i shows an error. Btw i have the full code already cause i copied from my dual boot windows and i wanted to try it here,

What should i do to make it work?

EDIT:
For everybody who has the same problem, it may be caused by the app version. I posted this on reddit cause i didn't get answer in time, and someone suggested that i download vs code with appimage, snap, or in my case pop!_os Installation.
MAIN POINT: Someone said that **NEVER** use **FLATPACK** with ides. It may work for other apps but never use it with ides. It can't handle system packages or modules.

Comment: Could you check that `tkinter` is in your virtual environment and not in the base environment? Also, is VS Code pointed to your `.venv` or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm a noob in programming and i don't know how to check them. Im pretty sure about it cause it says 'Python 3.10.6(.'venv':venv)' in the bottom right.

Comment: I checked and it is not in venv, cause i ran pip -V and i didn't get the path to the venv folder. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know what interpreter is currently used by vscode, which is displayed in the lower right corner of the interface.

[image]

Clicking on the displayed python version will open a **Select Interpreter** panel where you can select the interpreter with the `tkinter` package installed to run the code

[image]

Or you can install the `tkinter` package for the currently used interpreter.

```
<path-to-current-python.exe> -m pip install tkinter
```

---

**EDIT**

From your terminal information it can be seen that you have activated the virtual environment, but you are running the code with **Code Runner**.

[image]

As a reminder, Code Runner doesn't change interpreters as you select another interpreter in the *Select Interpreter* panel. So please use the `Run Pythonn File` option provided by the official **Python** extension to run the code.

[image]